# Issue with calling static template method inside a template class

Tags: c++

I have a template class and a static template method inside. I also have a simple function g, that just allows user to call this method in an appropriate way. This code gives me an error "expected primary-expression before '>' token" inside g function. But if I call a method inside g function like this:

`return A<types::a>::f<T>();`

In that case code compiles fine and gives no error. How can I possibly fix this issue and what is the problem?

```
enum class types : uint8_t
{
    a, b
};

template<types type>
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    static T f();
};

template<>
template<typename T>
T A<types::a>::f() {
    cout << "a" << endl;
    return T{};
}

template<>
template<typename T>
T A<types::b>::f() {
    cout << "b" << endl;
    return T{};
}

template<types type, typename T>
T g() {
    return A<type>::f<T>();
}

int main() {
    g<types::a, int>();
}
```

Comment: Is `types` an enum?

Comment: Yes, it's an enum. enum class types : uint8_t { a, b };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `template` keyword:

```
template<types type, typename T>
T g() {
    return A<type>::template f<T>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7q8D9y)

`A<type>::f` is a dependent name (depends on template parameter `type`). To correctly parse this statement when the template definition is encountered (as required by two-phase-lookup rules), the compiler has to know *before instantiation* whether `f` is a variable, a type or a template. It defaults to "it's a variable"; add `template` to denote a template or `typename` to denote a type.

Your other case works because in `return A<types::a>::f<T>();` there is no dependent name.